# Movie: aliens in meteors, attack a guy on a baseball field

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Meteors crash on Earth with aliens inside them. One alien waits in the trees near a baseball field. It attacks a guy that goes into the outfield to retrieve a ball. Later this guy is in his car driving and an alien rips out from inside his body. I think the alien in the field impregnated him.

Later on, the alien that came out of the guy shows up at someone's house in the window. An old man is with a kid and the old man shoots the alien with a shotgun.

One other thing I do remember is that when the alien was shot it kinda blew up and cracked apart spilling acid like blood I think, like in the *Alien* movies.

I was young and turned it off after the shotgun scene cause I was scared. late 80's early 90's. White people, set in USA. don't remember any actors. Medium budget I guess.  And I thought the old guy with the shotgun might be Wilfred Brimley but I checked his filmography and nothing seems to match up.

Comment: It impregnated him? After taking him to a baseball game as their first date? Classy.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that's not all you remember. When did you see it? Was it big-budget or small? Who was the main character? What did he or she look like? What did the aliens look like? What language did you see it in? Were the characters white, black, asian, other? Was the film in black&white or colour? Was it an adult film (e.g. with graphic gore) or a family film?

Comment: I was young and turned it off after the shotgun scene cause I was scared. late 80's early 90's. White people, set in USA. don't remember any actors. medium budget I guess. sorry like I said I was young it was long time ago. One other thing I do remember is that when the alien was shot it kinda blew up and cracked apart spilling acid like blood I think. like in the aliens movies. And I thought the old guy with the shotgun might be Wilfred Brimley but I checked his filmography and nothing seems to match up.

Comment: OK. Now [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/138785/edit) that into the question.

Comment: Were the aliens human-shaped?

Comment: A long shot, but could this be "[Slither](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0439815/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_48)"? Or "[Night of the Creeps](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091630/)"?

Comment: not slither, this movie was on tv in the late 80s or early 90s. I'll check out night of the creeps. they were human shaped.

Comment: not night of the creeps

Comment: I notice that a user with the same name suggested an edit. If you have lost access to your account, you can [reset your password](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/reset-password) or [merge your accounts](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Then you should be able to edit that information into the body of your question.

Comment: this may be one of the critter movies

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that you are look for [*Critters*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090887/) (1986), though it was M. Emmet Walsh rather than Wilford Brimley with the shotgun. Note that there were 3 other *Critters* movies.

The movie revolved around a bunch of alien criminals (the critters), the bounty hunters hired to take them out, and the small town that got caught in the crossfire.

The baseball scene was in there and the Walsh character shot one with a shotgun when the critters were breaking into the house of the character's family.

Here is a trailer for the first film. There is a shotgun bit about 44 seconds in:

Comment: Could you add why you think those are similar to the film described by the asker?

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re looking for *Not of This World* (1991).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102556/):

> An alien life form lands on earth and begins to feed off electricity, making it grow to enormous size. The authorities must stop it as it slithers cross-country towards a nuclear power plant.

Here is the full movie on YouTube:

Comment: What scenes make you think that's the one? I strongly suggest to [edit] your answer to include some clarifications or timestamps to look at in the video :)